# Python unit test mock, get mocked function's input arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want a unit test to assert that a variable `action` within a function is getting set to its expected value, the only time this variable is used is when it is passed in a call to a library.

```
Class Monolith(object):
    def foo(self, raw_event):
        action =  # ... Parse Event
        # Middle of function
        lib.event.Event(METADATA, action)
        # Continue on to use the build event.
```

My thought was that I could mock `lib.event.Event`, and get its input arguments and assert they are of specific value.

>Is this not how mocks work? The mock documentation frustrates me with its inconsistency, half-examples, and plethora of examples that are not related to what I want to do.

Comment: where have u used mock? you can mock `lib.event.Event` and assert

Comment: in retrospect, this the patch and mock approach seems so much more natural/defacto now then it did then

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use patch decorator and then call `assert_called_with` to that mocked object like this:

If you have this structure:

```
example.py
tests.py
lib/__init__.py
lib/event.py
```

And the content of `example.py` is:

```
import lib

METADATA = 'metadata_example'

class Monolith(object):

    def foo(self, raw_event):
        action =  'action_example' # ... Parse Event
        # Middle of function
        lib.event.Event(METADATA, action)
        # Continue on to use the build event.
```

And the content of `lib/event.py` is:

```
class Event(object):

    def __init__(self, metadata, action):
        pass
```

The code of `tests.py` should be like:

```
import mock
import unittest

from lib.event import Event
from example import Monolith


class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('lib.event.Event')
    def test_example1(self, event_mocked):
        # Setup
        m = Monolith()

        # Exercise
        m.foo('raw_event')

        # Verify
        event_mocked.assert_called_with('metadata_example', 'action_example')
```

Comment: what if i want to get the arguments passed to the mock as a dictionary?

Comment: @dopatraman You can either use [`call_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) or [`call_args_list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list).

Comment: @CraigAnderson Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It's not really an answer to the original question, is it? I've proposed an edit to this answer to illustrate how they might be used.

Answer (score 88):

You can use [`call_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) or [`call_args_list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list) as well.

A quick example would look like:

```
import mock
import unittest

class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('lib.event.Event')
    def test_example1(self, event_mocked):
        args, kwargs = event_mocked.call_args
        args = event_mocked.call_args.args  # alternatively 
        self.assertEqual(args, ['metadata_example', 'action_example'])
```

I just quickly written this example for somebody who might need it - I have not actually tested this so there might be minor bugs.

Comment: For me, I had to do `self.assertEqual(event_mocked.call_args[0], <expected_args>)`. `event_mocked.call_args.args` didn't work for me. Maybe a version issue?

Comment: @Josmoor98 If it is a version issue, it might help someone if you could share your Python version.

Comment: Indeed, as pointed out in the comments, python version - `Python 3.6.12  - [PyPy 7.3.3 with GCC 9.3.0]`

Answer (score 10):

If you want to access arguments directly, how about this?  A little redundant though...
See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.call.call_list

```
import mock
import unittest

from lib.event import Event
from example import Monolith


class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('lib.event.Event')
    def test_example1(self, event_mocked):
        # Setup
        m = Monolith()

        # Exercise
        m.foo('raw_event')

        # Verify
        name, args, kwargs = m.mock_calls[0]
        self.assertEquals(name, "foo")
        self.assertEquals(args, ['metadata_example', 'action_example'])
        self.assertEquals(kwargs, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above were helpful, but I wanted an easy way to write a unit test that wouldn't need refactoring when the tested code changed how the mocked function call was changed without any functional changes to go with it.

For instance, if I chose to call the function partially or completely by keywords (or build a kwargs dictionary and plug that in) without changing the values being passed in:

```py
def function_being_mocked(x, y):
  pass

# Initial code
def function_being_tested():
  # other stuff
  function_being_mocked(42, 150)

# After refactor
def function_being_tested():
  # other stuff
  function_being_mocked(x=42, y=150)
  # or say kwargs = {'x': 42, 'y': 150} and function_being_mocked(**kwargs)
```

This might be overkill, but I wanted my unit test not to worry about changes to the function call format as long as the expected values made it to the function call (even including specifying or not-specifying default values).

Here's the solution I came up with. I hope this helps simplify your testing experience:

```py
from inspect import Parameter, Signature, signature

class DefaultValue(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other_value) -> bool:
        if isinstance(other_value, DefaultValue):
            return self.value == other_value.value
        return self.value == other_value

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'<DEFAULT_VALUE: {self.value}>'

def standardize_func_args(func_sig, args, kwargs, is_method):
    kwargs = kwargs.copy()

    # Remove self/cls from kwargs if is_method=True
    parameters = list(func_sig.parameters.values())
    if is_method:
        parameters = list(parameters)[1:]

    # Positional arguments passed in need to line up index-wise
    # with the function signature.
    for (i, arg_value) in enumerate(args):
        kwargs[parameters[i].name] = arg_value

    kwargs.update({
        param.name: DefaultValue(param.default)
        for param in parameters
        if param.name not in kwargs
    })

    # Order the resulting kwargs by the function signature parameter order
    # so that the stringification in assert error message is consistent on
    # the objects being compared.
    return {
        param.name: kwargs[param.name]
        for param in parameters
    }

def _validate_func_signature(func_sig: Signature):
    assert not any(
        p.kind == Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD or p.kind == Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL
        for p in func_sig.parameters.values()
    ), 'Functions with *args or **kwargs not supported'

def __assert_called_with(mock, func, is_method, *args, **kwargs):
    func_sig = signature(func)
    _validate_func_signature(func_sig)

    mock_args = standardize_func_args(
        func_sig, mock.call_args.args, mock.call_args.kwargs, is_method)
    func_args = standardize_func_args(func_sig, args, kwargs, is_method)

    assert mock_args == func_args, f'Expected {func_args} but got {mock_args}'

def assert_called_with(mock, func, *args, **kwargs):
    __assert_called_with(mock, func, False, *args, **kwargs)

def assert_method_called_with(mock, func, *args, **kwargs):
    __assert_called_with(mock, func, True, *args, **kwargs)
```

Usage:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def bar(x, y=5, z=25):
    pass

mock = MagicMock()
mock(42)

assert_called_with(mock, bar, 42) # passes
assert_called_with(mock, bar, 42, 5) # passes
assert_called_with(mock, bar, x=42) # passes
assert_called_with(mock, bar, 42, z=25) # passes
assert_called_with(mock, bar, z=25, x=42, y=5) # passes

# AssertionError: Expected {'x': 51, 'y': <DEFAULT_VALUE: 5>, 'z': <DEFAULT_VALUE: 25>} but got {'x': 42, 'y': <DEFAULT_VALUE: 5>, 'z': <DEFAULT_VALUE: 25>}
assert_called_with(mock, bar, 51)

# AssertionError: Expected {'x': 42, 'y': 51, 'z': <DEFAULT_VALUE: 25>} but got {'x': 42, 'y': <DEFAULT_VALUE: 5>, 'z': <DEFAULT_VALUE: 25>}
assert_called_with(mock, bar, 42, 51)
```

Please note a caveat before using this. `assert_called_with()` requires reference to the original function. If you're using the decorator `@unittest.mock.patch` on your unit test, it might backfire as your attempt to look up the function signature might pick up the mock object rather than the original function:

```py
from unittest import mock

class Tester(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.mock.patch('module.function_to_patch')
    def test_function(self, mock):
        function_to_be_tested()
        # Here module.function_to_patch has already been replaced by mock,
        # leading to error from _validate_func_signature. If this is your
        # intended usage, don't use assert_called_with()
        assert_called_with(mock, module.function_to_patch, *args, **kwargs)
```

I recommend using `unittest.mock.patch.object` that requires you to import the function being patched as my code requires that for reference to the function anyway:

```py
class Tester(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_function(self):
        orig_func_patched = module.function_to_patch
        with unittest.mock.patch.object(module, 'function_to_patch') as mock:
            function_to_be_tested()
        
            assert_called_with(mock, orig_func_patched, *args, **kwargs)
```