# how to ignore order of the list parameter passed in for assert called in python unit test

Tags: python, python-unittest

In python unit test, I can assert a func is called with certain parameters

```
    func_mocker = mocker.patch("func_to_call")
    func_mocker.assert_called_once_with([1, 2, 3])
```

However, the order of this list does not matter and is not deterministic.
How can make sure calling it with [3, 2, 1] will also pass the assert above?

Comment: Why not assign the input argument to a variable and assert against that? If using pytest this is easily done by utilizing fixtures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python unit test mock, get mocked function's input arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129350/python-unit-test-mock-get-mocked-functions-input-arguments)

Comment: yes, but it is kinda ugly to manually add all these additional logic to check, adding a IGNORE_ORDER or something like ANY in the api might be more ideal

Comment: Use `func_mocker.assert_called_once()` instead of `func_mocker.assert_called_once_with([1, 2, 3])`?

Comment: There is not much of additional logic here to check - just order the list and compare it against the expected ordered list, e.g. something like `self.assertEqual([1, 2, 3], sorted(func_mocker.call_args[0]))'. And no, there is no such convience API.